# Baldur's Gate: Enhanced Edition Item List?

Tags: baldurs-gate-enhanced

Is there an up to date item's list containing all the items added (or removed)?

I found this:

http://mikesrpgcenter.com/bgate/index.html

But there are a number I have come across which aren't listed there.

Answer (score 3):

There is a wiki that has a list of the added items to BG:EE that can be found [here](http://baldursgate.wikia.com/wiki/New_items_Baldur%27s_Gate_EE)
and a forum post [here](http://forum.baldursgate.com/discussion/8110/a-guide-to-new-magic-items-spoilers/p1) that contains all the new items (and in the case of the forum post the item codes as well)